# How to select 'exceptions' in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table `comments` which contains a field `student_id`(foreign key to `students` table. 
I have another table `students`

What I would like to do, is run a query that displays all students who have not made any comments. The SQL I have, only shows students who have made comments

```
SELECT studentID, email, first_name, last_name FROM "students" JOIN comments ON students.id = comments.student_id
```

How do I 'reverse' this SQL to show students who have NOT commented?

Comment: All three answers below work perfectly, I have just not seen Mrunal and Gordon Linoff methods with the 's' so I will accept PhillipXT answer purely because this is the only style of SQL I have seen (note I am brand new to SQL, only started learning yesterday so please forgive my lack of knowledge)

Comment: The "s" is just an alias for the table name.  It can be a shortcut for a long table name, and it can also be used in sub-queries like Gordon Linoff had done to refer back to the tables in the parent query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT studentID, email, first_name, last_name
FROM students
LEFT JOIN comments ON students.id = comments.student_id
WHERE comments.student_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from comments c
                  where s.id = c.student_id
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.studentID, s.email, s.first_name, s.last_name from students s where s.id not in (select student_id from comments);
```